# How can I remove float margin or padding?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a `<nav>` and when I add the `float:right` property, it adds a `3px` or so `margin` to the top, if I don't put the `float`, everything works fine.

Here is the code

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li ><a href="#">UBICACION</a></li>
<li><a href="#">RESERVAS</a></li>
<li class="boton_chico"><a href="#">FOTOS</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and the CSS

```
 nav {
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#000;
    }

ul{ margin-top:0;}

ul li {
    font-family:'Gotham-narrow-light-botonera';
    list-style-type:none;
    }

ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    width:190px;
    height:10px;
    font-size:2em;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    margin-top:15px;
    }

ul li.boton_chico a{
    width:130px;
    text-align:center;
    }

body {
    background:url(imagenes/subtle_carbon.png) repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-color:#111;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: A fiddle that reproduces this issue would be helpful. Do you have any other code to post? Maybe it's an issue with another element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need here is a Basic reset like this [Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Because for default some elements like the `ul` has properties like `margin` or `padding` values. Also you can use this most basic reset where `*` match all the elements:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}
```

View a demo maked with your code here **http://jsfiddle.net/vy9ME/2/**

*PD: The recomendation is made the reset at the beginning of the CSS*